# How to handle data occlusion in d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a sort of raw distribution of the data with:

- X axis: Person (a or b)
- Y axis: Intensity (on a scale of 0 to 4)

Is there any way in which I can prevent data points from occluding each other? Such as, when there is an existing data point the next data point with the same value (different date) is positioned at an offset from it, as shown in the images below.

*Current status of the plot*
[image: Current status of plot]

*Desired status of the plot*
[image: Desired status of plot]

I am open to changing the data format to get the end result.

```
Dataset:

    condition   intensity   date
    a   2   1
    a   3   2
    a   0   3
    a   1   4
    b   3   5
    b   3   6
    b   4   7
    b   4   8
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.condition;
  }));
  y.domain([0, 4]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".point")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("square").size([500]))
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.condition) + "," + y(d.intensity) + ")";
    });
});


function type(d) {
  d.severity = +d.severity;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: You can consider adding some `alpha` to the points which will make overlapping points darker than the rest.

Comment: Alpha is a good solution but I need to be able to click the individual data point for some further interaction, hence the need to offset them :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way.

Store all the data points in an array and check for duplicates. If a duplicate is encountered, it is offset by 40 pixels along X-axis.

```
var arr = []; // array for holding all the datapoints
var tally = []; // array for storing the duplicates

// Change the squares
    svg.selectAll(".point")
      .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("square").size([500]))
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var current = (d.condition + "," + d.severity); // current data point
    var index = arr.indexOf(current); // get the index of current data point in array arr

if (index == -1) { // if index is -1, then no match found. unique data point
  arr.push(current); // push point onto array
  position = "translate(" + x(d.condition) + "," + y(d.severity) + ")";

} else {
  tally.push(current);
  var tallylen = tally.length;
  var tindex = tally.indexOf(current);
  for (var i = 0; i < tallylen; i++) {
    var c = 0;
    if (c == tindex) {
      position = "translate(" + (x(d.condition) + (40 * (i + 1))) + "," + y(d.severity) + ")";
    } else {
      c = tindex;
      position = "translate(" + (x(d.condition) + (40 * (i + 1 - tindex))) + "," + y(d.severity) + ")";
    };

  }
};
return position;
})
```

If someone has a better solution please post it.